# When user change the language of the app , It doesn't change the texts it change the layout direction

Tags: android, local

This is the first time I do that .I want to make a language selection in my app contains `Arabic` and `English` . I have a problem , When user change the language of the app , It doesn't change the texts it change the layout direction only .I have 2 `String` file . The original for `English` and the other `string-ar` for `Arabic` I searched and tried many solution . 
One of them is in [this article](https://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/)

And here is my code .

```
 public void setLocaleAr (){
    Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    Resources resources = getResources();
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics()); //deprecated
}
```

**Edit :** when I use my code . The texts in my `Spinner` changed . but the text which is in the `xml` file didn't change .

Comment: If the text is written directly inside XML, it won't change. Make sure the text inside the XML is referenced to a string in strings.xml e.g, android:text="@string/your_text".

Comment: I know . I use `android:text="@string/please"` but it didn't change .

Comment: each strings.xml file should be inside a language sepcific directory, for Arabic make sure that you have values-ar folder which has strings.xml file.

Comment: Please see my Edit in the question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used example from this article in many projects and it works great.

As it says in the article you need to update the text or any other language dependent resources one by one. Or you can call activity.recreate() to restart currently loaded activity. Then the activity will reload the resources with the correct locale. However, if you select this option your users will notice the affect because it will close your application and you get black screen for a very small amount of time and then recreate your activity again in meanwhile.

Comment: Will I use `recreate()` after clicking on the language ?

Comment: Yes you can try calling it there or if you have for example option to change language in Settings you can save some boolean value in SharedPreferences and look if the recreate() is necessary

Comment: Is there any solution instead of `recreate()` ?

Comment: Yes of course, you can call view.setText(getString(stringResId)) on every view in your layout to refresh resources.

Comment: If I did this solution what is the benefit of my code then ? I want a professional solution .

Comment: By the way I marked your answer as the right answer .

Answer (score 0):

The language and the other configurations are applied to an activity when that activity is creating. Therefore if you want the changes to be applied you need to recreate the activity by recreate() method.

Comment: Aha . But is there any solution instead of `recreate()` ?